# Retrieving class property when reading from database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have the following:

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("", dbCon))
                {
                    cmd2.CommandText = @"
                        SELECT [PCMF04_PCBPocketName_N]
                        ,[PCMF01_PcbConnectorName_N]
                        ,[PCMF03_PCBHeaderName_N]
                        ,[PCMF04_KeyIndex_C]
                        ,[PCMF04_SortOrder_R]
                        FROM [ArdSqlDev].[dbo].[WPCMF04_PCBPocket]
                        WHERE 
                            PCMF03_PCBHeaderName_N = @PCMF03_PCBHeaderName_N
                         Order By 
                            PCMF04_PCBPocketName_N";

                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PCMF03_PCBHeaderName_N", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = header.HeaderName;

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var pocket = new PcbPocket(dr.GetString(0));
                            pocket.PocketName = dr.GetString(0);
                            pocket.PcbConnector.ConnectorName = dr.GetString(1);
                            pocket.KeyIndex = dr.GetString(3);
                            pocket.SortOrder = dr.GetInt32(4);
                            header._PcbHeaderPockets.Add(pocket);
                        }

                        return header;
                    }
                }
```

I get an error on line:

```
pocket.PcbConnector.ConnectorName = dr.GetString(1);
```

Error:

> Error  2   Property or indexer 'PcbConnector.ConnectorName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

**Pocket Class**

```
  public partial class PcbPocket : IEquatable<PcbPocket>, IComparable<PcbPocket>, IComparable
        {
        public PcbPocket(string PocketName)
        {
            _PocketName = PocketName;            
        }

        private string _PocketName = string.Empty;
        public string PocketName
        {
            get { return _PocketName; }
            set { _PocketName = value; }
        }

        private string _KeyIndex = string.Empty;
        public string KeyIndex
        {
            get { return _KeyIndex; }
            set { _KeyIndex = value; }
        }

        private int _SortOrder = 0;
        public int SortOrder
        {
            get { return _SortOrder; }
            set { _SortOrder = value; }
        }

        private PcbConnector _PcbConnector = null;
        public PcbConnector PcbConnector
        {
            get { return _PcbConnector; }
            set { _PcbConnector = value; }
        }
```

**Connector Class**

public partial class PcbConnector : IEquatable, IComparable, IComparable
    {

```
    private Collections.PcbConnectorPinList _PcbConnectorPins = new Collections.PcbConnectorPinList();
    public Collections.PcbConnectorPinList PcbConnectorPins
    {
        get
        {
            return _PcbConnectorPins;
        }
        set
        {
            _PcbConnectorPins = value;
        }
    }

    public PcbConnector(string connectorName)
    {
        _ConnectorName = connectorName;       
    }

    public PcbConnector(PcbConnector pcbConnector)
    {
        _ConnectorName = pcbConnector.ConnectorName;
        _Height = pcbConnector.Height;
        _Width = pcbConnector.Width;
        _Active = pcbConnector.Active;          
        _Supplier = pcbConnector.Supplier;
    }


    private string _ConnectorName = string.Empty;
    public string ConnectorName
    {
        get { return _ConnectorName; }
    }

    private string _Supplier = string.Empty;
    public string Supplier
    {
        get { return _Supplier; }
        set { _Supplier = value; }
    }


    private float _Height = 0;
    public float Height
    {
        get { return _Height; }
        set { _Height = value; }
    }

    private float _Width = 0;
    public float Width
    {
        get { return _Width; }
        set { _Width = value; }
    }

    private bool _Active = true;
    public bool Active
    {
        get { return _Active; }
        set { _Active = value; }
    }
```

PcbPocket and PbcConnector are classes.  ConnectorName is a property of the PbcConnector class.  If I ignore this line, that value will be null, which is not what is saved in the database as and will give me an object reference not set error.  Is there a way I can retrieve my ConnectorName value to show in my datagridview (in a different file/form)?

Comment: it would help to show the `PcbPocket` class and whichever class `PcbPocket.PcbConnector` is.

Comment: `PcbPocket.PcbConnector.ConnectorName` is a `ReadOnly` or `get-only` property: i.e. is has no `set` attached to it. There is probably a constructor for `PcbPocket` or `PcbPocket.PcbConnector` that does what you want. Or maybe a `PcbPocket.PcbConnector.SetConnectorName` etc.

Comment: also do you create a new instance of PcbConnector as you said it was a class

Comment: @Jonesy edited my question to add my classes.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the problem is pretty obvious. Did you try googling the error message first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have a setter on your PcbConnector:

```
private string _ConnectorName = string.Empty;
public string ConnectorName
{
    get { return _ConnectorName; }
}
```

you want:

```
private string _ConnectorName = string.Empty;
public string ConnectorName
{
    get { return _ConnectorName; }
    set { _ConnectorName = value; }
}
```

with that said, you should note that properties can be auto-implemented, if you're not concerned about their default value.  For example, you have:

```
private int _SortOrder = 0;
public int SortOrder
{
    get { return _SortOrder; }
    set { _SortOrder = value; }
}
```

this is the same as

```
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

as an `int`'s default value is 0 anyways

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `PcbConnector` class. Change it like this

```
class PcbConnector
{
    // Now
    public string ConnectorName {get; private set;}

    // Update this to
    public string ConnectorName {get; set;} // makes the set public
}
```